# Can dataframe row loop be avoided when indexing previous or next row?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a data set which I want to individually assign a unique value to every time it reaches zero.

The code I've come up with seems slow and I suspect there must be a faster way of doing it.

```
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#--------------------------------
#     DEBUG TEST DATASET
#--------------------------------
#Create random test data
series_random = np.random.randint(low=1, high=10, size=(10000,1))

#Insert zeros at known points (this should result in six motion IDs)
series_random[[5,6,7,15,100,2000,5000]] = 0

#Create data frame from test series
df = pd.DataFrame(series_random, columns=['Speed'])
#--------------------------------

#Elaped time counter
Elapsed_ms = time.time()

#Set Motion ID variable
Motion_ID = 0

#Create series with Motion IDs
df.loc[:,'Motion ID'] = 0

#Iterate through each row of df
for i in range(df.index.min()+1, df.index.max()+1):

    #Set Motion ID to latest value
    df.loc[i, 'Motion ID'] = Motion_ID

    #If previous speed was zero and current speed is >0, then new motion detected        
    if df.loc[i-1, 'Speed'] == 0 and df.loc[i, 'Speed'] > 0:
        Motion_ID += 1
        df.loc[i, 'Motion ID'] = Motion_ID

        #Include first zero value in new Motion ID (for plotting purposes)
        df.loc[i-1, 'Motion ID'] = Motion_ID

Elapsed_ms = int((time.time() - Elapsed_ms) * 1000)

print('Result: {} records checked, {} unique trips identified in {} ms'.format(len(df.index),df['Motion ID'].nunique(),Elapsed_ms))
```

The output from the above code, was:

> Result: 10000 records checked, 6 unique trips identified in 6879 ms

My actual data set will be much larger, so even in this small example I'm surprised it took so long for what seems like a simple operation.

Comment: You can do it with a while loop, and keep going until you find the next 0. Assign the previous all the values a unique number and the next segment another number. For say, starting from 0 you found 0 at 9th position. Fill up the data frame till 9th position with 0 and from 9th onwards repeat the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can express the logic using boolean arrays and expressions in numpy without any loops:

```
def get_motion_id(speed):
    mask = np.zeros(speed.size, dtype=bool)

    # mask[i] == True if Speed[i - 1] == 0 and Speed[i] > 0
    mask[1:] = speed[:-1] == 0
    mask &= speed > 0

    # Taking the cumsum increases the motion_id by one where mask is True
    motion_id = mask.astype(int).cumsum()
    # Carry over beginning of a motion to the preceding step with Speed == 0
    motion_id[:-1] = motion_id[1:]
    return motion_id


# small demo example
df = pd.DataFrame({'Speed': [3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1]})
df['Motion_ID'] = get_motion_id(df['Speed'])
print(df)
   Speed  Motion_ID
0      3          0
1      0          1
2      1          1
3      2          1
4      0          2
5      1          2
```

For your 10,000 row example I see a speed up of around 800:

```
%time df['Motion_ID'] = get_motion_id(df['Speed'])
CPU times: user 5.26 ms, sys: 3.18 ms, total: 8.43 ms
Wall time: 8.01 ms
```

Comment: I like this method, as adding more conditions is trivially easy and there's no loop at all. Thanks!

Comment: @RockyK yes, I think using numpy arrays is often a good fit for this kind of problem in python because numpy is that much faster than plain python even if it is wasteful from algorithm point of view (extra memory, sometimes unnecessary loops etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is by extracting the index value of 0 from `df` and then iterating over those index values to check and assigning the value of `Motion Id`. Check below code:

```
Motion_ID = 0

#Create series with Motion IDs
df.loc[:,'Motion ID'] = 0
i=0
for index_val in sorted(df[df['Speed'] == 0].index):
    df.loc[i:index_val,'Motion ID'] = Motion_ID
    i = index_val
    if df.loc[index_val+1, 'Speed'] > 0:
        Motion_ID += 1

df.loc[i:df.index.max(),'Motion ID'] = Motion_ID+1
#Iterate through each row of df
```

Output :

```
Result: 10000 records checked, 6 unique trips identified in 49 ms
```

Comment: Much quicker, though it still uses a loop. Second-last line though results in the last Motion ID to be +2 from previous. Easy fix.